# Close color box using Another button - cant able to close why?

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

Hi similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316942/closing-colorbox)

I tried every solutions in the above condition.But not working for me.I have included colorbox and Jquery in overlaypage and the parent page.If I am not included on the overlay page then I cant able to call the close function It display the error colorbox  not defined.In my color box the following code is displayed.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/Jquery.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery.colorbox.js'></script>
<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>
<tr>

    <td ><div id='cboxcancelbtn'  style='cursor:pointer;'> Cancel</div>
</tr>
 </table>
 <script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function()
{
      $('#closepopupbox').click(function()
    {
                $('#cboxClose').click();
        //$.colorbox.close();
    });
      });
   </script>
```

I tried lot but not working .I tried this one also but no luck

```
  <td ><div id='cboxcancelbtn' onclick='parent.closeColorbox(); return false;'> Cancel</div></td>
  <script>
    function closeColorbox() {
                $.fn.colorbox.close(); 

                     } 
   </script>
```

What I did the mistake.How can I make it work.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
```

(instead of)

```
$.fn.colorbox.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove parent from `parent.closeClorbox()` on your onclick event or remove the onclick event and try this:

```
$('#cboxcancelbtn').click(function(){
  $.fn.colorbox.close();
})
```